# How do I fix this error in C ( Invalid write of size 1 error )

Tags: c, valgrind

I just started learning C. I completely have no idea where I miss. It keeps saying Invalid write of size 1 error. How do I fix this ? Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{

    char *origdest = realloc(dest,(strlen(dest) + strlen(src))*sizeof(char) + 1);
    while (*dest)
    {
        dest++;
    }

    while (*src)
    {
        *dest++ = *src++; // Copy the source
    }
    *dest = 0;

    return origdest;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *str = malloc(7);
    strcpy(str, "Aatami");

    str = mystrcat(str, "Beetami");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works here: https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/UnripeFocusedAutomatedinformationsystem#main.c

Comment: You need to do `if(origdest != NULL) dest = origdest;`. There's a realloc FAQ somewhere, I can't be bothered to find it.

Comment: Well, adequate documentation for realloc is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: You need to track the size of memory allocated for `dest`. For the same reason library `strcat()` doesn't `realloc()`

Answer (score 1):

```
char *origdest = realloc(dest,(strlen(dest) + strlen(src))*sizeof(char) + 1);
```

After this point, one of the three things happen:

1. Resize-in-place has happened. `dest == origdest`.
2. Resize-in-place did not happen, copy-to-new-buffer happened instead. `origdest` now points to a suitably sized block of memory that contains a copy of what `dest` used to point at, and `dest` is an *invalid pointer*. Any operation on `dest` is undefined behaviour.
3. Resize has failed. `origdest == NULL`.

Your program will only work if case 1 takes place.

If case 3 takes place, you should indicate an error and exit, or recover. The latter is hardly an option for a simple exercise, so insert

```
assert (origdest != NULL);
```

below the call to realloc.

Now if case 2 takes place, you want to restore the invariant which is guaranteed by case 1 and which your code relies on.

```
dest = origdest;
```

should do the job.

I would recommend to rename `origdest` to `newdest`, because this is a *new* destination, not the *original* one.

Finally, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, just omit it, or at least use it consistently if you do not want to rely on this fact. `(strlen(dest) + strlen(src) + 1) * sizeof(char)` reflects the intent better.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qWKd8hW4K)

Comment: This is a really good answer that accurately explains why the programme didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors/mistakes I would suggest you the following:

1. Typecase the malloc call with a specific pointer (malloc returns void* which is a kind of generic one, so you have to typecast it to char* in this case)
2. Same goes for realloc.
3. It's better to use malloc to allocate memory for new pointer.
4. Put a NULL check filter after alloc calls to check whether memory is allocated to your pointer or not.